# mulitiple database select php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have 2 databases on the same server with 2 identical tables.

What I want to do is select all records from both tables and join them in one array.
I've been messing around with the script below. For some reason it returns the records of db2.tbl twice and doesn't return the db1.tbl records at all. When I try to select the data from a single database is works fine for both of them. Does any one see the problem?

```
<?PHP
 require_once("config.php");

$conn = @mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass)or die ('Error connecting to mysql server'.mysql_error());
$q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM db1.tbl JOIN db2.tbl");
var_dump(mysql_num_rows($q));
while($arr = mysql_fetch_assoc($q)){
    var_dump($arr);
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want ? All records from database1 followed by all records from database2:

```
$q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM db1.tbl UNION SELECT * FROM db2.tbl");
```

I assume the user you are connecting with has access to both databases.

Comment: Never `SELECT *` in a `UNION`, particularly if you don't know the tables have equivalent columns (since the OP didn't say they do)

Comment: He said so in the first line ;) But I agree you should be explicit.

Comment: Thanx that is exaclty what i needed. I will keep in mind that for future projects a SELECT * is a no no ;), but for this project it works fine like this.

Answer (score 0):

Your query should work. However add tilt(`) to your database name table name. Execute the query first in mysql see whether it is ok than execute with php.